# How to start child Activity from Fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am using Fragment activity in place of tab Group Activity. like this.

```
public class TabGroup1Activity extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {

        return null;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);

    return (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container,
            false);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

it starting activity not as child (starting in full screen)
but I don't know how to start as child.

please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activities are designed to take up the whole screen, while Fragments are designed to take up all, some, or none of the screen. You shouldn't be extending `Fragment` for your `Activity`, do this instead.

```
public class TabGroup1Activity extends FragmentActivity {
```

You do not want to start an `Activity` inside your `FragmentActivity`, you need to create a new `Fragment` and add it to a layout container in your `TabGroup1Activity`'s layout, using `getSupportFragmentManager()` or `getFragmentManager()` with a `FragmentTransaction`.

See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: that's wrong we can re size a activity and also its possible to create a floating activity like a dialog.

Comment: @Abhijit Google recommends that you use `Fragment`s for UI elements that take up only part (or none of the screen). They suggest you use them for dialog, tab groups, and more. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html. So yes you can use an `Activity` in a non full screen manner, but it is not a best practice. Please read the documentation next time.